# how to properly resize the table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

my question is why does the table cell not resize when I put these codes, I tried both ways and it still does not work. Also does the number of section and number of rows in section functions got to do anything as being the problem.

```
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

    //these 2 functions are supposed to do the same as the two lines of code above 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}




func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

---

Here are the constraints I have on the tableview:

```
tableViewContraints.append(table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10))
tableViewContraints.append( table.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 10))
tableViewContraints.append( table.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -10))
tableViewContraints.append( table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor))
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(textViewContraints)
```

---

here is the table cellForRowAt

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yeet", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = papel[indexPath.section]
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "butterfly")
    cell.sizeToFit()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    let sizp = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
    let textView = UITextView(frame: sizp)
    textView.backgroundColor = .green
    cell.addSubview(textView)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: show a picture/s of how you set constraints

Comment: Agreed. It will resize based upon constraints, which haven’t been shared w us thus far. FYI, you don’t need/want the `heightForRowAtindexPath` or `estimatedHeightForRowAt` methods, as it’s less efficient than just setting those two properties.

Comment: Here are the constraints I have on the tableview,   tableViewContraints.append(table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10))
        tableViewContraints.append( table.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 10))
        tableViewContraints.append( table.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -10))
        tableViewContraints.append( table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor))
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(textViewContraints)

Comment: @Jose show the cellforrow method code

Comment: here is the cellForRow Method, func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        table.tableFooterView = UIView()
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "solo", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.section]
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.sizeToFit()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
   return cell
    }

Comment: Help solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the constraints for your text view, I’d suggest you define them solely between the text view and its superview.

So, if adding it programmatically, you’d add it to the content view of the cell, and define the constraints between the text view and the cell’s content view:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var textView: UITextView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(textView)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.textView = textView

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
    }
}
```

Note the disabling of the scrolling, which instructs the text view to use its intrinsic size to determine its height.

Anyway, then my view controller is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let strings = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                   "Praesent quis nisl justo. Sed ipsum lacus, consectetur quis varius a, ornare sit amet nisl. Curabitur vulputate felis quis pulvinar maximus. Donec sem lorem, ultrices sed ultricies ac, placerat sit amet purus. Nam elementum risus justo, vitae tincidunt mauris sodales vitae. Integer id fermentum quam. Vivamus a arcu neque. In consectetur, velit in sollicitudin finibus, quam nibh rutrum augue, sed dignissim purus ex id elit. Duis sit amet volutpat sapien. Ut leo sapien, iaculis sit amet ultrices eget, fringilla nec dolor.",
                   "Etiam aliquam risus vitae cursus mollis. Fusce vulputate nisi sodales est euismod rutrum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla dignissim ante sed massa viverra, in lobortis ligula semper. Maecenas placerat nec erat ut malesuada."]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    }

}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return strings.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.textView.text = strings[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

All of that having been said, I’d probably add the text view and its constraints, set its properties, etc., right in the storyboard cell prototype and then hook up an outlet, and then my cell is radically simplified:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
}
```

That achieves precisely the same result with less code. But by showing my code above, you get a sense of precisely what I’d set up in IB.

Comment: The table is inside a veiwcontroller, can you do one inside a viewController?

Comment: @Jose - You just need to hook up `@IBOutlet` and set delegate and data source in IB. I’ve revised the answer and as you see, the code changes are trivial.But don’t get lost in the details here. Focus on the big picture observation, namely (a) add the constraints when you create the cell and its text view; (b) these constraints are between the text view and its superview; and (c) turn off scrolling if you want the text view to have its height set by the amount of text initially in the text view.

Comment: What is contentView?

Comment: Every table view cell has a `contentView`, to which we add our content (rather than to the cell itself). The reason you do that is that if a disclosure indicator is added, that’s to the right (in a LTR language), and the content view is adjusted accordingly. You want your content to respect that, so that’s why we add it to the `contentView`. The basic idea of the code above is that we add our content with top, bottom, left, and right constraints to the `contentView`, and if we then use `.automaticDimension`, the cell will be resized for us based upon the intrinsic size of the content.

Comment: can you do an example with a button inside?

Comment: Just add the button as a subview and add the constraints. Why don’t you take a crack at it? I’m not sure what the stumbling block is.

Comment: Thank Rob for helping out, can we send message here? Incase I need your help again